# A set of mutually overlapping intervals

Tags: general-topology, geometry, elementary-set-theory

I need a reference for this elementary result which I assume to be true and known. Adding a citation in the paper I'm writing (even to a problem in a textbook) would be faster and more elegant than adding the proof itself (which may elude my decaying brain):

Given a finite set *S* of real closed intervals, if each pair of intervals has an overlap (intersection) of length at least *k*, then the intersection of all the intervals in *S* has length at least *k*.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathcal{S}=\big\{ [a_i,b_i] \big\}_{i=1}^n$ is your collection of closed intervals, then you can denote

$$ a:= \max a_i \quad \text{and} \quad b:=\min b_i. $$

Note that $[a_i,b_i] \cap [a_j,b_j] \neq \emptyset$ implies $b_j\geq a_i$ or $a_j\leq b_i$ Your assumption means that $b_i-a_j \geq k$ for all $i,j$. Since $a= a_{i_0}$ and $b=b_{j_0}$ for some $1 \leq i_0,j_0\leq n$, you get that

$$ b-a = b_{j_0}-a_{i_0}\geq k. $$

If $b>a$, then $[a,b]\subseteq \cap_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i]$.

This solution is a bit simple so I am bit suspicious. Your question also reminds me of [Helly's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem), which might be adapted for a proof of your statement. But this seems like a simpler solution to me.